# how to create a class and return something. Swift

Tags: swift, class

I am trying to create multiple languages for my app, so I want to translate a English word to a different language word, but I am not sure how to create a class and return the translated word like `Translate("hello")` and it would return `你好`. Any suggestions instead of creating a function as I don't want to do something like `Translate().convert("hello")` and get the return of "你好"? Thanks.

```
class Translate {
    let englishToChineseDict = [
                                "hello": "你好",
                                "hi": "你好"
                               ]
    init(english: String) {
        let word = englishToChineseDict[english]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your app support multiple languages, first you need to add the localization in the project settings:

Select your project file on the left pane, then add a localization in the "Localizations" section:

[image]

Click the "+" button and select Chinese (Traditional), check all the checkboxes:

[image]

I recommend you to also localize to Simplified Chinese. So after checking those checkboxes, the thing should look like this:

[image]

You will see that some new `.strings` files are added to the project:

[image]

You can localize your app just by editing these files. In the files, you will see something like this:

```
"uel-mS-zq9.text" = "some text";
```

You basically translate the right hand side of the `=` sign to the desired language. Simple as this:

```
"uel-mS-zq9.text" = "一些文字";
```

And you do this for all the text that needs translating.

But sometimes, some text that needs translations is not in the storyboard. To translate those, you need to create a new file called `Localizable.strings` and check these checkboxes on the file inspector:

[image]

Again, you'll find a `Localizable.strings` file created for each of the localizations.

If you write something like:

```
"Settings" = "設定";
```

in the Traditional Chinese file, calling `NSLocalizedString("Settings", comment: "")` will return 設定.

For more info, you can check [this](https://cg2010studio.com/2013/05/10/ios-%E5%A4%9A%E5%9C%8B%E8%AA%9E%E7%B3%BB-localization/) or [this](http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/) out.

Comment: Although helpful if the OP's snippet is his actual multilingual implementation this isn't really an answer to the question

Comment: Judging by OP's name, he/she's clearly a Chinese person from Hong Kong, Guangdong or Malaysia. @HeddevanderHeide

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I am from Hong Kong. I need some time to digest what you guys say. I will vote later. Thank you for the helps:)

Comment: @PakHoCheung I have added another link. That tutorial is written in swift.

Comment: This one is easy. One more question. Is it possible to let user switch the language in my app by using this approach? I can think about a method to do it if creating a Translate class.

Comment: @PakHoCheung yes of course! There are a lot of good answers about that on stack overflow. Just do a search! If you're lazy, you can go to cocoapods.org and search for "localization" there. You will find lots of libraries that do just that!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no properties to initialize an `init` method is not needed but a `translate` method.

```
class Translate {
    let englishToChineseDict = [
                                "hello": "你好",
                                "hi": "你好"
                               ]
    func translate(english : String) -> String {

      if let result = englishToChineseDict[english] {
         return result
      } else {
         return "The term \(english) is not in the dictionary"
      }
    }
}
```

And use it by creating an instance of the class and call the method

```
let translator = Translate()
let chinese = translator.translate("hi")
```

---

Alternatively use a static class

```
static let englishToChineseDict = [ ...
...
class func translate( ...
```

and call it

```
let chinese = Translate.translate("hi")
```

**Edit**:

Swift classes don't return anything (with the exception `nil` in a failable initializer) but as a workaround you could implement the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol which changes the class pointer to a string representation.

```
class Translate : CustomStringConvertible {
  let englishToChineseDict = [ "hello": "你好", "hi": "你好" ]

  var english : String

  init(_ english : String) {
    self.english = english
  }

  var description : String {

    if let result = englishToChineseDict[english] {
      return result
    } else {
      return "The term \(english) is not in the dictionary"
    }
  }
}


let chinese = Translate("hi")
print(chinese) // "你好"
```

Comment: Um. I am thinking about something like Int(1.5) will get 1. Can I use similar method to get the translated word? like Translate("hi") will get "你好"

Comment: @PakHoCheung just shortcut translator.translate any way you like?

Comment: but Translate("hi") does not return a string, how can I make it to String? Is there any way to return as String instead of using .description

Answer (score 1):

`init` method is used to initialize the property of object, try to create another function and use that like this

```
class Translate: NSObject {

    struct Static {
        static var instance: Translate?
    }

    class func sharedManager() -> Translate {
        if (Static.instance == nil)
        {
            Static.instance = Translate()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    let englishToChineseDict = [
        "hello": "你好",
        "hi": "你好"
    ]

    func translateWord(english: String) -> String {
        if let word = englishToChineseDict[english] {
            return word
        }
        else { 
            return "Chinese word not found for english word \(english)"
        }
    }
}
```

Now call this method like this

```
let str = Translate.sharedManager().translateWord("hello")
```

**Note:** I have created shared (singleton) object of the `Translate` class, so you can access singleton object from Any class using `sharedManager` method. So you no need create new instance of of `Translate` class.

**Edit:**

```
class Translate: NSObject {

    let englishToChineseDict = [
        "hello": "你好",
        "hi": "你好"
    ]

    var translatedWord = String()
    var isTranslated = false

    init(english: String) -> String {
        if let word = englishToChineseDict[english] {
            translatedWord = word
            isTranslated = true
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call like this

```
let translate = Translate("Hello")
if translate.isTranslate {
    print(translate.translatedWord)
}
```

Comment: @vadian Now it will not crash. :)

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the additional code to make Translate act as a singleton

Comment: The singleton syntax is outdated: The modern recommended syntax is just one line `static let sharedManager = Translate()`. It replaces the `Static` struct and the `sharedManager()` function.